# A probability measure that takes only the values $0$ and $1$ but is not a point mass

Tags: measure-theory

> Show that there exist probability $P$ on $( \Omega, F )$ such that $P(B)$ is 1 or 0 yet $P$ is not a point mass for all $B$ belonging to $F$

Omega={1,2,3,4,5,6} F=sigma({1,2,3,4},{3,4,5,6}).

Comment: Do we have any special knowledge about $\Omega$ and $F$?

Comment: If $\Omega$ is a one-point set, there is no such $P$.

Comment: Let  $\Omega$ be $[0,1]$.  Let $F=\{A \in [0,1] \,|\, A \textrm{ or } A^c \textrm{ is at most countable}\}$ .  Then $F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.  Define $P$ on $( \Omega, F )$ by  $P(A)=0$ if $A$ is at most countable and   $P(A)=1$ if $A^c$ is at most countable.   Then $P$ is a probability, for all $B \in F$, $P(B)$  is either $1$ or $0$ and yet $P$  is not a point mass probability.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, I guess you haven't heard of measures on fractals?

Comment: It might help to explicitly write out $\mathcal{F}$ (as I'm sure you now know how to do from a previous question). Then we can choose which sets to have probability $1$ and which sets to have probability $0$ in order to properly specify your probability measure. From doing this you may realize that your $\sigma$-algebra cannot distinguish $1$ from $2$, $3$ from $4$, or $5$ from $6$, in the sense that there is no $A \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $1 \in A$ and $2 \not \in A$ (and similar for the other pairs).

Comment: Oh, you mean that each set in F is composed of more than one element right?

Comment: I got this thanks you are good at explaining stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let  $\Omega$ be $[0,1]$.  Let $F=\{A \in [0,1] \,|\, A \textrm{ or } A^c \textrm{ is at most countable}\}$ .  Then $F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.  Define $P$ on $( \Omega, F )$ by  $P(A)=0$ if $A$ is at most countable and   $P(A)=1$ if $A^c$ is at most countable.   Then $P$ is a probability, for all $B \in F$, $P(B)$  is either $1$ or $0$ and yet $P$  is not a point mass probability.

Answer (score 1):

Any nonprincipal ultrafilter on $F$ will do the job. A subfamily $S \subset F$ is called a filter if it satisfies the following axioms:

1. For any $R_1, R_2 \in S$ we have also $R_1 \cap R_2 \in S$
2. For any $R \in S$ and $R \subset R'$ we have also $R' \in S$
3. Each element of $S$ is nonempty

Since each filter is just a subset of $F$ it makes sense to say $S_1 \subset S_2$ if each set in $S_1$ is also a set in $S_2$. We define an ultrafilter to be a filter which cannot be 'enlarged' in this way. The family of filters on $F$ form a partially ordered set. And the maximal elements are exactly the ultrafilters.

Since $F$ is closed under complements there is a different characterisation of its ultrafilters $-$ For every set $A \in F$ any ultrafilter must have either $A$ or $A^c$ as an element. You should prove the following lemma.

**Lemma:** If $U \subset F$ is an ultrafilter then define a map $\mu : F \to \{0,1\}$ by $\mu(A)=1 \iff $ $A \in U$ and $\mu(A)=0$ otherwise. Then $\mu$ is a measure.

Then we just have to find an ultrafilter. The search for maximal elements can, as usual, be accomplished by using Zorn's lemma. In this case on the poset of filters.

However there is no guarantee this will give a non-atomic measure. Since the maximal element might look like $\{A \in F : f \in A\}$ for some atom $f \in \Omega$. Ultrafilters which don't look like this are known as nonprincipal.

To avoid this problem first find a filter which has empty intersection. Then apply Zorn's lemma to the poset of all filters that extend it.

Comment: If probability is required to be countably additive, then I don't believe just **any** nonprincipal ultrafilter will do the job. I think you need a countably complete nonprincipal ultrafilter.